# Rethinkdb chef solo cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, rethinkdb

Is there any RethinkDB chef solo cookbook that allows one to install latest rethinkdb on ubuntu 14.04 / AWS.

I tried couple options, however it didn't help.

https://github.com/vFense/rethinkdb-chef - how to install latest version?
https://github.com/sprij/rethinkdb-cookbook.git - source compilation takes hours

I would appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the cookbook that is available from the community repository first:

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/rethinkdb

It claims to be integration tested on Ubuntu. If it doesn't work under chef-solo, then I'd advise you to switch to local mode chef client instead.

https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/10/31/chef-client-z-from-zero-to-chef-in-8-5-seconds/

PS
Also checkout Berkshelf for managing cookbook dependencies. It's a standard tool in the [chefdk](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/)

Answer (score 0):

I updated [rethinkdb-chef](https://github.com/vFense/rethinkdb-chef) to work with the latest version of RethinkDB as well as removed the network portion of the .kitchen.yml file. I validated that this does work on CentOS 6 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I still need to write tests as well as documentation. As per Marks answer, try to use the community supported version 1st. I created this cookbook, so that I can customize it as per my needs with [vFense](https://github.com/vFense/vFense).